# Having trouble with creating a variable that adds to itself

Tags: python, csv, variables

I have a variable in my code (named totalPrice) which will set itself to a price given and then when the user adds a product to their list it will add that price to totalPrice. However, when running it, it resets the variable to 0. I believe it has something to do with the placement of it as I have placed it inside a subprogram. I do not know what to do with it as I can't seem to find a place for it.

My code is as follows:

```
import csv
import sys
import re
import os

addItem = ""
gtinNum = ""
quantity = 0
restart = ""

f = open("ChocolateCSV.csv", "rt")
global receipt
receipt = open("receipt.txt", "w+")

def restart():
    restart = input("Would you like to restart? Y/N")

    if restart.lower() == "y":
        gtinQuestion()
    else:
        global receiptCont
        receiptCont = receipt.read()
        receipt.close()
        print(receiptCont)
        print("Total Price: " + "%.2f" % round(totalPrice, 2))
    sys.exit()

def quantityQuestion():

    quantity = input("How much would you like?")
    if quantity.isdigit() == False:
        quantityQuestion()
    global price
    price = ""
    global totalPrice
    totalPrice = 0

    with open("ChocolateCSV.csv", 'r') as file2:
        for row in csv.reader(file2):
            if str(gtinNum) in row:
                receipt.write(str(row) + "\n")
                receipt.write(str("- Quantity: " + quantity + "\n"))
                price = float(row[2]) * int(quantity)
                totalPrice += price 
                receipt.write("- Price: " + str("%.2f" % round(price, 2)) + "\n")
                restart()
                break

def gtinQuestion():
    global gtinNum
    gtinNum = input("Please enter the GTIN-8 Code of the product you would like to order:")

    if gtinNum.isdigit() == False or len(gtinNum) != 8:
        gtinQuestion()
    elif gtinNum.isdigit() == True and len(gtinNum) == 8:
        quantityQuestion()

gtinQuestion()
```

Comment: Move it after import block.

Comment: Shouldn't it be both after the import block and after restart.lower == 'y'?

Comment: @Alex.S I get the error about the variable being referenced before assignment when I do that

Comment: @Ashafix see my comment to Alex, and if it is after the restart.lower() == 'y' it will reset. I dont want it to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`totalPrice` is not global within `restart()`.

also think of re-designing your code, there's a lot of dangerous recursion and global variables. E.g. `if quantity.isdigit() == False:` within `quantityQuestion` calls `quantityQuestion` and continues despite the error with the computation.

The whole point of having functions is to hide computation and variables inside. Use function parameters etc and learn clean python (try `import this` within a python console).

Comment: I can see what you mean by putting it in the restart() but it gives me an error if I leave the totalPrice set to nothing. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Forget the keyword `global` exists, it only gets beginners into trouble. And to amplify DomTomCat's answer, work through some tutorials, your code sample is obnoxiously bad.